# AMD OpenCL Reduce Register Pressure

Tags: optimization, opencl, cpu-registers, amd-gpu

I am running a sorting algorithm in a kernel, and the sorting part uses about 36 VGPR, thus resulting in 12.5% occupancy and awful performance.

The code segment is as follows:

```c
typedef struct {
  float record[8];
  float dis;
  int t_class;
} node;


for ( int i = 0 ; i < num_record ; i ++ ){
  in_data [ i]. dis = Dist ( in_data [i]. record , new_point , num_feature );
}


node tmp ;
int i;
int j;
#pragma unroll 1
for ( i = 0 ; i < num_record - 1 ; i ++ )
  for ( j = 0 ; j < num_record - i - 1 ; j ++ )
  {
    if ( in_data [ j]. dis > in_data [ (j + 1) ]. dis )
    {
      tmp = in_data [ j ];
      in_data [ j ] = in_data [ (j + 1) ];
      in_data [ (j + 1) ] = tmp ;
    }
  }
```

Is there any way to reduce the register usage without big modifications to the algorithm itself? I guess it would be better to reduce the register under 16.

Update:

Basically the kernel is trying to implement exhaustive knn method.

Comment: That code segment is only using `sizeof(node)` registers, and cannot be further optimized. Can you post a little bit more of code? The size of launch would also be interesting to measure the allocated memory values.

Comment: How could you tell? The code segment actually used 36 VGPR. The node is a structure with 9 floats and 1 int. @DarkZeros

Comment: If you read my comment, I said `sizeof(node)`, if node has 10 elements, then is logical it will not use 1 register, but many more. Additionally, the VGPR may be influenced by code you have not posted, unless your algorithm just swaps the same 2 positions all the time.
A good option would be to code element by element of the structure, to avoid using 320 bits in the temporal variable, but I am sceptical if that would work, or the compiler will optimize it anyway.

Comment: Do you have access to CodeXL (I imagine you do since that's typically how you would measure the register usage)? Maybe posting the relevant generated IL would help.

Answer (score 0):

```
float tmp;

tmp = in_data [ j ].x;
in_data [ j ].x = in_data [ (j + 1) ].x;
in_data [ (j + 1) ].x = tmp ;

tmp = in_data [ j ].y;
in_data [ j ].y = in_data [ (j + 1) ].y;
in_data [ (j + 1) ].y = tmp ;

tmp = in_data [ j ].z;
in_data [ j ].z = in_data [ (j + 1) ].z;
in_data [ (j + 1) ].z = tmp ;
```

should be using 1/3 of registers of the original code since it needs only 1/3 space at a time.

You could also do a global--->local ------> global

instead of global -----> private -----> global to reduce private register usage.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I remember, AMD is famous for using lots of registers when using loop unrolling. If your `num_record` is a fixed value known to the compiler, it may do some unrolling, and create copies of `tmp` as well.

Can you try setting pragma unroll, or declaring the `tmp` parameters inside the loop?

**Possibility 1:**

```
node tmp;
#pragma unroll
for ( int i = 0 ; i < num_record - 1 ; i ++ )
 #pragma unroll
 for ( int j = 0 ; j < num_record - i - 1 ; j ++ )
 {
  if ( in_data [ j]. dis > in_data [ (j + 1) ]. dis )
  {
   tmp = in_data [ j ];
   in_data [ j ] = in_data [ (j + 1) ];
   in_data [ (j + 1) ] = tmp ;
  }
}
```

**Possibility 2:**

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < num_record - 1 ; i ++ )
 for ( int j = 0 ; j < num_record - i - 1 ; j ++ )
 {
  if ( in_data [ j]. dis > in_data [ (j + 1) ]. dis )
  {
   node tmp = in_data [ j ];
   in_data [ j ] = in_data [ (j + 1) ];
   in_data [ (j + 1) ] = tmp ;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think unrolling would help? Cause in my point, unrolling the loop would increase the register pressure for sure .   Does AMD do loop unrolling automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description your `node` structure looks more or less like this (I'm assuming `dis` is an `int` but it doesn't matter whether is really `int` or `float`):

```
struct node
{
    int dis;
    float f1;
    ...
    float f9;
};
```

If simple changes won't help ... how about adding one more field `index` to `node` which would make it possible to uniquely identify the node (unless this can be done with one of the existing fields) and introducing `node2` structure which would contain only `index` and `dis`?
Something like this:

```
struct node
{
    int index; // add index for uniqueness unless one of f1 ... f1 could do
    int dis;
    float f1;
    ...
    float f9;
};

struct node2
{
    int index; // add index for uniqueness unless one of f1 ... f1 could do
    int dis;
};
```

Then use `node2` for sorting and after in another kernel or on the host sort `node` using `index` of already sorted `node2`.

This should reduce the register pressure in sorting kernel but will require more changes like already said introduction of new `node2` and possibly kernel splitting.